# Winkel Tripel and Robinson Projections?

Tags: geography, projection

How can I do WorldPlot with the WorldProjection -> Winkel Tripel or Robinson projections.
Mathematica has Mollweide and several others defined, but not these popular projections adapted by National Geographic.

Comment: It seems [`WorldPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/WorldPlot/ref/WorldPlot.html) is obsolete. Try [`CountryData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CountryData.html), *i.e.* `CountryData["World", {"Shape", projection}]` where `projection` is `"WinkelTripel"` or `"Robinson"`.

Answer (score 10):

To make Rahul Narain's answer in comment a full answer:

```
CountryData["World", {"Shape", "WinkelTripel"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

"WinkelTripel" can also be used in projection functions like `GeoGridPosition`:

```
GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[{37., -109., 0}, "ITRF00"], "WinkelTripel"]
(* GeoGridPosition[{-1.404416661, 0.6926031128, 0}, "WinkelTripel"] *)
```

In Mathematica 10, functions like [GeoGraphics](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoGraphics.html) will be able to use projections like this even more easily.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. I have not used `WorldPlot` or `CountryData` before so I was not confident that I was interpreting the question correctly.

Comment: @Rahul You're welcome. I have been using WorldPlot before and can tell you that the current CountryData maps are much, much better. Mathematica 10 maps seem to improve on this even more.

Comment: Thank you very much, Rahul and Sjoerd. You guys' replies are really helpfull.